# How to marshal a macro in C# script?

Tags: c#, macros, interop, dllimport

If you have a macro like this in C:

```
 #define SLICE_VERSION 20110614
```

How to use this macro in C# Script?

Should I marshal it? How?

Should I re-define it in C#? I know C# does not have #define macro but maybe I can just define it as a static variable.

Or can I refer to it somehow?

Similarly, if you have a global variable in C, how do you use it in C# script?

I have seen tutorials about marshaling classes, structures, arrays, unions and lots of other things from C/C++ to C#, but I haven't been able to find any hint about how marshal a constant... Or do I have to marshal it? Can it be referred to directly?

BTW, I found this a pretty good tutorial about interopping on Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I re-define it in C#?

Yes.  In C#, you'd want to use a `const`:

```
const int SLICE_VERSION = 20110614;
```

That being said, I'll often rename this to make it more C#-standard, as well:

```
const int SliceVersion = 20110614;
```

Depending on how it's being used, you make wish to specify an [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) explicitly, as well.  Also, depending on the usage, you may want to use a different type (Int32 may not be correct - you may want UInt32, etc.).  One disadvantage to macros in C/C++ is that they are not strongly typed, so without seeing the usage, there is no way to know the exact type expected here.

Comment: Thanks! I will do it in this way. The calling function is expecting an uint, so I will just define it as a const uint...